# Linked server query occasionally returns results slowly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have an unfortunate situation where I need to pull a next-number from a table from both a local and a linked server.  To do so, I've created a stored procedure to return the result.  When I execute the procedure on the local server, it is always blazing fast (0.00X seconds).  When I execute the procedure via a linked server, it is almost always fast (0.01X seconds).  However, I will occasionally (maybe once an hour) see it hang - it'll run anywhere from 2 - 60 seconds.  In tracing on both servers, I can see the procedure ran as expected on the local server's trace:
[image]
However, the trace on the linked server shows it taking much longer:
[image]

So in this example, while the local SQL instance returned the results in 0.008 seconds, the linked server did not receive them for 22+ seconds.

There are no messages in the Windows log indicating any type of communication error between the two servers.  In fact, they are both on the same cluster.

The procedure is always returning a single row via an OUTPUT clause.

EDIT: I am able to see the wait while the linked server query is running is PREEMPTIVE_COM_QUERYINTERFACE.
[image]
I have determined this is being caused by the Distributed Transaction Coordinator.  If I don't use it, the hanging does not occur. The MS DTC runs in the OS - how do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Perhaps you want to run a trace on the remote server and check the DNS and AD performance.

Comment: How do I do that?  Is that a wireshark thing?  I'm a DBA and not experienced in such things.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)